# RXJS catch error in forkJoin observable array

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a routine that gathers Observables into an array and then forkJoins them.

```js
// Contains X post requests.
let obs: Observable<any>[] = [];
let numberExecuted: number = 0;
let failed = [];
forkJoin(
    obs.map(o =>
      o.pipe(
        catchError(e => {
          failed.push(e);
          return of(null);
        }),
        tap(() => {
          numberExecuted++;
        })
      )
    )
  )
  .subscribe(() => {})
  .add(() => {
    // Display what succeeded / failed.
  });
```

I would like to save which requests failed / succeeded into arrays to be displayed in a dialog after the routine completes. My logic right now is not catching failed requests and storing the errors. The failed array is always [] after the subscription completes despite there being failed requests.

Comment: this code looks like it works: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-master-gzjhk8?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: @bryan60 You are absolutely correct. It seems to have been an error with the API I was using. It was returning a default value instead of throwing an error like expected. Thank you for the help. You validating that my code was correct directed my attention to the API.

Comment: dev tools / network tab is your friend